# opus decoding in ffmpeg: how to pass target sample rate and ensure libopus decoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

As I understand, `ffmpeg` compiled with `--enable-libopus` has two opus decoders: builtin and `libopus`. I am decoding an opus file to wav.

1. How can I know which opus decoder is being used by `ffmpeg`?
2. `opusdec` has an option `--rate` which can directly downsample to the needed sample rate. When I use `ffmpeg` for decoding an opus file and set `-ar`, the decoding time grows x6 from the baseline 10sec (for a 3Mb, 2hour opus file). For `opusdec`, the decoding time is same regardless of used `--rate`. So I suspect that `ffmpeg` has some bug or duplicates resampling work. For workaround, is there a way to pass an option to `ffmpeg` to pass it down to `libopus` and to emulate the effect of `--rate`?

Thank you!

**UPD**
Adding `-acodec libopus` in the beginning of ffmpeg command clearly does something (forces `libopus` decoder?) and completes decoding in 6.2sec. When I add `-ar 8000`, it slows down to 7.3sec. I would assume, it's still too large of a change for a fair effect of downsampling (for `opusdec` `-ar 8000` actually speeds things up, not slows it), so maybe `ffmpeg` has a decoder configuration / resampling bug even when `libopus` decoder is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libopus decoder in ffmpeg will only output at a fixed rate of 48000 Hz. Using `-ar` leads to resampling using the swresample library.

Comment: It appears that you're right and the `sample_rate` is reset at [`avc->sample_rate    = 48000;`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/libopusdec.c#L65). It's a shame that there is no way to save compute and resample directly to the requested `sample_rate`... I guess the proper way would be to introduce special libopus decoder options if `-ar` is supposed to only affect post-hoc `swresample` processing.

Comment: *introduce special libopus decoder options* --> this possibility will depend on whether the resampling is taken care of by the decoder directly or does opusdec delegate it to a bundled resampler. If the latter, then it will be the responsibility of the libopus decoder *wrapper* in ffmpeg to insert a resampler and that won't be allowed since ffmpeg architecture guidelines don't allow mixing of resampling inside a decoder interface. That violates clean separation of library roles. That said, you haven't posted your command and log, so I can't check if you've unnecessary compute in your runtime.

Comment: I'll check if I can repro on a synthetic file and will post full ffmpeg command lines. `libopus` can do resampling to the target sample rate directly during decoding, but it appears that `ffmpeg` doesn't let the user access this functionality. It also appears post-hoc resampling severely affects wall clock time for the `builtin` opus decoder case (no such bad difference for `libopus` decoder)